# Story about school bully and victim transported to a magical land

Tags: story-identification

This is a shortish (maybe novella-sized) story about two kids in school who get sent to the principal's office for fighting. Instead of entering the office, they are transported to some sort of magical land. They get some magical equipment, like a bowl in which food appears when the bearer needs to eat. There is speculation by the kids that earth technology (specifically, television was mentioned) wouldn't work in that world, symmetric to how we don't have magical food bowls in our world. The kids have to work together to defeat some sort of enemy. I recall they have two halves of a disc (shaped maybe like a yin and a yang) that they have to fuse together and use as a discus sort of weapon. Upon doing working together to do so, I *think* they also fuse together into one person who grows huge and is able to fight the monster (which I can't remember any details of). When they get back to our world, they find no time has passed and they're still in front of the principal's office door, but they no longer hate each other.

I remember reading this in seventh grade (1993).

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where?

Comment: I was (maybe ironically) afraid to offer too many spoilers in case someone hasn't read this thing that I can't remember the title of :-P. I'll add any more details I can think of.

Comment: Just go mad, anything you think is too spoilery just hide behind spoiler markup --> `>!...` But really any answerers will not care about spoilers, as they're looking for extra info to find the book, and any people coming here will be looking for the book as well after having read it, so it's not a problem. And as our top user @Valorum said [Spoil as much as possible](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36517237#36517237)

Comment: @Edlothiad - Agreed. Spoil as much as you possibly can, **especially** twist endings and dialogue.

Comment: @Valorum, you cold-hearted person, not the *twist-endings*!!!

Comment: @ChrisSunami: Thanks. That does look to be a match, but our policy is to not close until it's confirmed. Although, this one is such a match, we might be able to just do it if Roni does not come back...

Comment: Ah, thank you @ChrisSunami! This is it!

Comment: So, technically this seems to be a duplicate of that question, but my question contains more details to help identify the book, and may be more useful to future searchers. Is there a protocol for that?